# How to locate specific property in ANT if the xml property file provided to ant has repeating xml elements

Tags: ant

I am trying to read a property file (xml) in ANT.

### Following is the sample data.

```
<WebLogicDomain>
    <Domain>MyDomain</Domain>
    <Environment>DEV</Environment>
    <Servers>
        <Server id = '1'>
            <Host>Host1</Host>
            <Port>14100</Port>
            <AliasName>adminserver</AliasName>
            <IsAdmin>true</IsAdmin>
            <AdminServerHost>adminHost</AdminServerHost>
            <ClusterName>#NA</ClusterName>
            <MinHeap>512MB</MinHeap>
            <MaxHeap>2048MB</MaxHeap>
        </Server>
        <Server id = '2'>
            <Host>Host2</Host>
            <Port>14110</Port>
            <AliasName>managedserver01</AliasName>
            <IsAdmin>false</IsAdmin>
            <AdminServerHost>adminHost</AdminServerHost>
            <ClusterName>Cluster1</ClusterName>
            <MinHeap>512MB</MinHeap>
            <MaxHeap>2048MB</MaxHeap>
        </Server>
    </Servers>
</WebLogicDomain>
```

---

With this property file I can easily access Domain & Environment properties but How do I get specific Server Properties?
If I need to get ${WebLogicDomain.Servers.Server[1].Host} i.e Host present at index 1, how do I get that?

Follwoing doesn't work as expected.

```
<project name="SampleProject">
    <xmlproperty file="buildproperties.xml" />
    <target name="init">
        <echo> ******** XML property file has been loaded. ******** </echo>
        <echo> Domain name is : ${WebLogicDomain.Domain}</echo>
        <echo> Environment is : ${WebLogicDomain.Environment}</echo>
        <echo> First Server Details are : ${WebLogicDomain.Servers.Server[1].Host} </echo>
    </target>
</project>
```

When I run the init target, I get following error.

```
init:
     [echo]  ******** XML property file has been loaded. ********
     [echo]  Domain name is : MyDomain
     [echo]  Environment is : DEV
     [echo]  First Server Details are : ${WebLogicDomain.Servers.Server[1].Host}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Ant's `xmlproperty` task finds multiple elements with the same name in the same location, it saves them to a single property as a comma-delimited list. Try using the `xmlproperty` task to view all the properties that your build has loaded, along with corresponding nested elements. DOM information, unfortunately, is mostly lost. You can try to rely on the order in which the properties are listed, using regex to extract the relevant information, but this will almost certainly be awkward and unreliable.

```
<xmlproperty file="weblogic.xml" />

<echoproperties prefix="WebLogicDomain" />
```

Output:

```
[echoproperties] #Ant properties
[echoproperties] #Thu Feb 15 16:42:17 PST 2018
[echoproperties] WebLogicDomain.Domain=MyDomain
[echoproperties] WebLogicDomain.Environment=DEV
[echoproperties] WebLogicDomain.Servers.Server(id)=1,2
[echoproperties] WebLogicDomain.Servers.Server.AdminServerHost=adminHost,adminHost
[echoproperties] WebLogicDomain.Servers.Server.AliasName=adminserver,managedserver01
[echoproperties] WebLogicDomain.Servers.Server.ClusterName=\#NA,Cluster1
[echoproperties] WebLogicDomain.Servers.Server.Host=Host1,Host2
[echoproperties] WebLogicDomain.Servers.Server.IsAdmin=true,false
[echoproperties] WebLogicDomain.Servers.Server.MaxHeap=2048MB,2048MB
[echoproperties] WebLogicDomain.Servers.Server.MinHeap=512MB,512MB
[echoproperties] WebLogicDomain.Servers.Server.Port=14100,14110
```

If you really need to do XML parsing that is more complicated than basic string retrieval, there's a 3rd party plugin called XmlTask that can accomplish this. http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/

```
<taskdef name="xmltask" classname="com.oopsconsultancy.xmltask.ant.XmlTask">        
    <classpath location="lib/xmltask.jar"/>
</taskdef>

<target name="default">
    <xmltask source="weblogic.xml">
        <copy path="WebLogicDomain/Servers/Server[@id='1']/Host/text()" property="server.1.host"/>
    </xmltask>

    <echo message="${server.1.host}" />
</target>
```

Output:

> [echo] Host1

Comment: While working on this I used javascript.

I put the javascript inside one target ("Tokenize") & called that target inside  "main" target. I kept 3 properties tokenString, tokenIndex & tokenVal.
However when I define <target name="main" depends="tokenize" .....
It works as expected 
It doesn't work when I do following,
 <target name="main">
  <antcall target="tokenize">
   <param name="tokenString" value="abc,xyz,efg"/>
   <param name="tokenIndex" value="1"/>
  <echo> ${tokenVal}</echo>
 </target>

Comment: @Prats That is expected behavior. When you run the `antcall` task, a new Ant subproject is started and any properties or references set within it will no longer be available once that subproject completes. Using the `depends` attribute is the proper way to do what you're attempting.